# VS Code: login to TFS not with a password, but a smartcard

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfvc

I'm trying to connect VS Code to our corporate TFS/TFVC.

When executing "Team: Signin", it asks for a username and password, which I don't have. I usually (also in Visual Studio) enter my corporate email address, then a dialog pops up where I can authenticate myself via smartcard.

I also tried to authenticate via token but I couldn't see where to enter it.

How can I successfully log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFVC is just a kind of source control similar to Git. One is centralized and the other is distributed.

So you should login to TFS not TFVC. According to your description, not able to use smart card to connect through VS code. This seems to be a known issue:

- [Unable to connect to TFS using smart card](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/issues/435)
- [Can't signin to on-prem TFS 2018 with smartcard](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/issues/400)

Besides, Personal access tokens (PATs) **are alternate passwords** that you can use to authenticate into Azure DevOps. When use it, just leave the user name empty and enter password with PAT token.

When you are using it, please navigate to `https://tfsurl/{teamprojectcollection}/_usersSettings/tokens`, and make sure your PAT is still in validity period. If not, please create new token by clicking 'New Token' button.

---

**Update**

But PAT is only work when you connect to Azure DevOps Service in VS code. If your repository is on Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 or later, you will be prompted to **enter your username and password**.

> **Team Foundation Server**
>
> If you are connecting to Team Foundation Server, **you will only need
>   your NTLM credentials (domain name, server name and password)**. It is
>   assumed that you have the proper permissions on the TFS Server.

For more details you could refer our official link with **Authentication** part: [Azure Repos Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)

You could also take a look at this blog which also mention this point-- [How to integrate TFS in Visual Studio Code](https://medium.com/@hubfly/how-to-integrate-tfs-in-visual-studio-code-part-1-8fddf7027d4b)

Comment: I updated the title to tfs.
Regarding the token. I have a valid one...but when I leave the username blank, vscode doesn't ask for a password. Instead it just shows an error.

Comment: Hi Mr. Smith Sorry, I just test with my azure devops service account, it works well with PAT.  But  for azure devops server,  seems not available.  You will only need to use your NTLM credentials (domain name, server name and password). It is assumed that you have the proper permissions on the TFS Server. After both are provided, they will be stored securely on your computer and used to connect to your TFS server. Have updated my reply.

Comment: We have TFS Version 16.131.28507.4.
Sorry I don't know what NTLM is... where do I get the credentials from?

Comment: This is TFS2018 Update 3.2, `where do I get the credentials from` Usually when we add users in TFS project is to add groups defined in  Active Directory (AD). This user account and password should be the one you used to login in your domain such as `Domianname\Smith`  or `Smithxx@Domianname.com`  and password. If you always use smartcard to authenticate, better to connect your TFS admin or IT department to get the password. There should be a password for your domain account even you are using smart card. Hope it's clearly.

Comment: Hi @Mr. Smith, any update on this issue? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve? If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer* which will also help others in the community.

Comment: Hi, I had no luck getting these credentials, so I couldn't test it yet. However, it seems that this is the right solution, although I haven't tested it. I marked it as the answer.